# Receber e ler array vindo por Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma requisição `ajax` assim

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "valor="+val,
    url: "ajax/mostra_imagens.php",
    success: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Na página `mostra_imagens.php` ele cria um `array` que por sua vez é recebido na variável `e` mas como é que eu faço para a variável `e` ser um `array` e não uma `string`?

***mostra_imagens.php***

```
<?php
require "../../ligacao.php";
$array = array();
$query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM publicidades_sponsors where id_publicidade = '".$_POST['valor']."'");
while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $array[] = $mostra['nome'];
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

O que o `console.log(e)` devolve

```
Array
(
    [0] => DIDAXIS1.png
    [1] => DIDAXIS2.png
    [2] => DIDAXIS3.png
    [3] => DIDAXIS4.png
)
```

Ele devolve dados diferentes consoante o que for selecionado no `select`

Comment: o que sai em `console.log(e)`? Aperte f12 e veja na aba console

Comment: pode colocar na pergunta um exemplo do é retornado?

Comment: Coloca a sua string que está sendo retornada na pergunta.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Editei a Pergunta

Comment: @MayconF.Castro Editei a Pergunta

Comment: @Marconi Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, eu consegui de certa forma o que queria fazer.

```
while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $array[] = $mostra['nome'];
}
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value.",";
}
```

Com este código ele cria uma string separada por vírgulas que posso vir a utilizar em seguida.

```
success: function(e){
    var slice = e.slice(0,-1);
    expl = slice.split(",");
        for(t=0;t<=balance;t++){
            if(n_pub-1<=t){
                r=0;
            }
            console.log("???"+expl[r]);
            $(".images"+p+" .images_pub").html("<img src='pubs/"+valor+"/"+expl[r]+"' style='width:100%' /><div class='altera' style='margin-top:-20px;top:0;left:2px;position:absolute;color:white;'><small><small><small><b>"+pub+"</b></small></small></small></div>");
            p++;
            r++;
        }
}
```

Com isto eu obtenho o que precisava. Usando o `slice(0, -1)` retiro a última vírgula para não dar conflito e criar outra posição no `array` criado com o `split(",")`.

Answer (score 1):

Tens algumas opções.

Podes usar a opção `dataType` do jQuery, assim ele tenta adivinhar o tipo de resposta do servidor dependendo do MIME enviado na mesma, se não controlas isso ou preferes não mudar, podes colocar este valor como `json` para e o jQuery vai transformar a resposta num objecto javascript (se possível).

```
$.ajax({
    // ... outras opcoes
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Também podes fazer tu, no `success` a conversão, sem precisar de usar o `dataType` acima.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(e) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(e));
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Com os novos detalhes colocados na pergunta, o que está acima não é válido. Mas continua a ser uma opção viável quando a API retorna JSON correcto, mas que o jQuery não o interpreta como tal.

Comment: Se executar o `JSON.parse` em array (no exemplo que foi dado na pergunta) da erro

Comment: Vi agora o update a pergunta. Não tinha o output da chamada ajax ontem, e pensei que fosse json válido. Estando como está sim, o JSON.parse não vai funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente como seu array está vindo, mais para você varrer um array você pode usar o [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```js
var array = [3, 2, 3, 4];
$.each(array, function(index, val) { 
  console.log("Indice: " + index + " Valor: " + val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No mostra_imagens.php, podes fazer assim, no lugar do `print_r()` do teu exemplo,

```
<?php
    require "../../ligacao.php";

    $array = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM publicidades_sponsors where id_publicidade = '{$_POST['valor']}'");
    while ($mostra = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $array[] = $mostra['nome'];
    }

    // Troca o print_r() pela linha de baixo.
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com muita dúvida de como retornar um array de um php usando JQuery, procurei várias formas e sempre era bem complicado. Então efetuando alguns testes descobri que era muito mais fácil do que eu pensava. Então resolvi compartilhar.

Estou usando meu o select do meu crud, mas no caso de buscar as informações do mysql, vocês coloquem a forma q desejar.

```
<button type='button' id='1' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='ModalEditar(this.id)'>Alterar</button>
```

**Aqui é o Jquery que vou usar para exibir em modal.**

```
function ModalEditar(id){
$.post('require/jp/jpvisitantes.php',
{
    modalEditar:true,
    id:id,
},
function(res){
    var arr = $.parseJSON(res);
    $('#ModalVisitantes').modal('show'); //exibir no modal primeiro, senão, não exibe os dados
    $("#nome").val(arr[0]);
    $("#cpf").val(arr[1]);
    $("#rg").val(arr[2]);
});
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
extract($_POST); //recebe todas as informações enviada via post e cria as variaveis automaticamente.

if(isset($modalEditar)){
    $visitante=$crud->select('visitantes', 'WHERE id = '.$id);
    foreach($visitante as $dt){
        $dado[0] = $dt['nome'];
        $dado[1] = $dt['cpf'];
        $dado[2] = $dt['rg'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dado); //retorna a variavel dado
}
```

**Modal que receberá a informação:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalVisitantes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div>Nome:
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" maxlength="90" required>
              <input type="hidden" id="id"/>
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%; float:left; min-width:150px;">CPF:
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" maxlength="14" required="required">
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%; float:left; min-width:150px;">RG:
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" maxlength="90">
            </div>
          <br />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```